# In Intellij IDEa, how to set a rule for automatically excluding the folders that match it from indexing?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEa automatically excludes folders with a name like "target" for example. I want to define a rule for automatically exclude some folders depending on a specific pattern instead of excluding all of them manually.

Comment: exclude them from a version control system? If so, put your pattern in the ignore file.

Comment: Does [Ignore files and folders](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-types.html) work for you?

Comment: They have already excluded from versioning. These folders are created in the building phase (like "target" folder). To avoid to get their files in searches, I want them marked as "excluded", but I want to do it automatically.

Comment: It seems "ignore files and folders" doesn't exclude files from indexing because after invalidating cache, unwanted files are anyway returned in searches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go into your `project settings`  -> `Modules` menu.

Choose the right module and mark the folder you don't want to index as `excluded`.

This is the only way to do it. There is no automatic way to that.

[image: Mark folder as excluded]

If you have really to many folders to exclude, you can go into your `PROJECT/.idea/modules` folder.
You should have an `iml` file for every module in your project.
You will find a structure like

```
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../..">
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../.gradle" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../build" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../node_modules" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
```

You should be able to add all your exclude folders using some bash magic.

HTH

Comment: I already know this procedure. Unfortunately, I have to repeat it too many time considering branch switchings and buildings. Thanks :)

Comment: @GeorgeLordsofCastle Note the last sentence, "add all your exclude folders using some bash magic". Use a `post-checkout` hook to update the `*.iml` files after switching branches. Not exactly the easiest thing to do, but doable. I'm about to implement this myself for a project if I can't find an easier way. Same issue.